# Operand is not showing in output

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator, operands

I am making calculator using html, css and javascript.HTML and CSS are working but I have issue in javascript as I am still a beginner. I first made a logic to store operands(+,-,*,/) in a variable operand and display it on screen by using innerHTML but operand is not showing in output.I tried using join("") to convert it into string thinking it may display it but it did not.

```js
var operand="";
function store(button) {
    if (button.value=="+" || button.value=='-' || button.value=='*'   || button.value=='/') {
        operand=button.value;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=operand.join("");
}
```

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.num{
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
.number_Btn{
    width: 16%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.zero{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.ope{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20%;
    height: 140px;
}
.operators{
     width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;        
}
.display{
   
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.display p {
    margin: 0;;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    </style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cal.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cal.js">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="number_Btn">
            <div class="numbering">
                <div class="three">
                    <button value="7" class="num" onclick="store(this)">7</button>
                    <button value="8" class="num" onclick="store(this)">8</button>
                    <button value="9" class="num" onclick="store(this)">9</button>
                </div>
                <div class="six">
                    <button value="4" class="num" onclick="store(this)">4</button>
                    <button value="5" class="num" onclick="store(this)">5</button>
                    <button value="6" class="num" onclick="store(this)">6</button>
                </div>
                <div class="nine">
                    <button value="1" class="num" onclick="store(this)">1</button> 
                    <button value="2" class="num" onclick="store(this)">2</button>
                    <button value="3" id="thr" class="num" onclick="store(this)">3</button>
                </div>
                <div class="zero">
                    <button value ="0" class="num" onclick="store(this)">0</button>
                    <button value ="=" class="num" onclick="store(this)">=</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ope">
                <button class="operators">+</button>
                <button class="operators">-</button>
                <button class="operators">*</button>
                <button class="operators">/</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="display">
            <p id="demo">display</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=operand.join("");` is not inside the function so it only runs once, on initial page load, when `operand` is still empty. (PS you absolutely do not need, or want, that `.join("")` here.) If you move that inside the `store` function it will work as you intend, because now the HTML will be updated when the button is pressed.

Comment: I did this but when It is not displaying output. Then I concatenated dummy text  with it and it only shows dummy text not the operand.  Check this line   :
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=operand+"demo_Text";
}

Comment: You are using `button.value` on buttons that don’t have a `value` attribute…

Comment: Also, the buttons don’t have the `onclick` handler I see now. You should add both the `value` and `onclick` to the buttons with class `operarators` and you are closer to what you want.

Comment: THANKS!!!! It worked. can you tell me any websites or books for javascript so that I can be better at it?